# Separate "internal" from "external" documentation in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I want to document a library with doxygen. The documentation will be read by two classes of people: Users, which are only interested in the external API and developers which want to see documentation for all functions/structures.

I would like to use to separate doxyfiles to create the documentation. Is there some "tag" I can put in a comment block to mark a comment as internal/external?

Comment: What language is the library? In C# for example, I believe doxygen can look at `public` vs `internal` function modifiers..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set **INTERNAL_DOCS**:

```
# The INTERNAL_DOCS tag determines if documentation
# that is typed after a \internal command is included. If the tag is set
# to NO (the default) then the documentation will be excluded.
# Set it to YES to include the internal documentation.

INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
```

In the documentation, you can use `\internal` or `@internal` at whatever granularity you want (file, function, etc.).

Comment: You saved me a lot of pain trying to get cond or if doing the same thing.

Comment: the \internal almost never does what you think it does. It only hides the documentation not the classes or functions that its being used with. I would strongly recommend using the \cond <tag> / \endcond mentioned by Mad Physicist in another answer.

Answer (score 14):

Use the **\cond** command:

`\internal` (`@internal`) only has granularity for the current comment block. It does not allow you any way to hide a structure definition in C.

The easiest way to do this is put

> \cond INTERNAL

at the top of an internal header file and

> \endcond

at the bottom. Then, in your configuration file, you add

> ENABLED_SECTIONS = INTERNAL

to allow the internal items to be included in the documentation.

This way is also recommended by Doxygen users, e.g. [here](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/How-to-set-internal-tag-for-consecutive-members-td4106.html)

Comment: Doxygen link is dead.

Comment: Can try this link: https://marc.info/?l=doxygen-users&m=125311238907871 ? Near the top of the list when you google "doxygen how to set internal flag for consecutive members".

Comment: Oh yeah. Didn't think of checking the link URL for googling clues...

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple solution which makes use of the fact that you can usually distinguish the internal and external parts of your code into files.

You can simply limit the input files to only those header files which you want to expose in the external documentation:

```
# For internal, we parse all files
INPUT = ./
# For external, we parse only the files containing the public interface
INPUT = include/header1.hpp include/header2.hpp
```

This has the advantage that the source files do not have to be modified (with `\internal` or `@internal`).